# Problem with data hash only storing last entry in loop

Tags: merge, hash

**1:** I'm creating a `data` hash object and then looping through a collection of entries to store the results of various macros in it:

```
{% set data = {} %}
{% set people = craft.entries().section('people').all() %}
```

**2:** I'm setting a reference to each entry and then merging the content compiled into my `data` object:

```
{% for person in people %}
    {% set i = loop.index %}

    {# get and set key|values #}

     {% set data = data|merge({
        i: {
            "key": value, 
            "otherKey":  otherValue
        }
    }) %}
{% endfor %}
```

**3:** And then I'm looping through my `data` object for output:

```
{% for row in data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ row.key|raw }}</td>
        <td>{{ row.otherKey|raw }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The structure of the output at stage 3 is fine, but it's only resulting in 1 `row` out of 45 `people` entries.

What am I doing wrong at 2 please?

Answer (score 2):

For the hash key to be dynamic, you must wrap it in parentheses:

```
(i): {
```

Comment: Awesome, it works! Thanks Brandon